# React can't pass state value to state array

Tags: reactjs

In React i have state property called random with a random value. I'm trying to select myArray2 value with random state and pass it inside myArray state.

When i click button, alert method should show one of the random numbers but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';



class App extends Component {

  //random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

this.state = {
    random: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
    myArray2:['one','two','three'],
    myArray:this.state.myArray2[this.state.random]     
};

}

change = () => {
  alert(this.state.myArray);
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.change}>ok</button>
      </div> 

    );
  }


}

export default App;
```

**THIS IS WHAT I GET-**

TypeError: Cannot read property 'myArray2' of undefined

**THIS IS WHAT I WANT-**

alert method showing random number

Comment: for each request you should pass new random integer, in this example random filled once with a random int and never change by each request

Comment: @Pleinair, any luck on integrating a solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something you currently cannot do with a class-based component. You can however just have your `change()` function execute the random logic on its own and effectively update the random and myArray state.

`this.setState()` has a 2nd argument for call-backs which gives us access to the updated state. Use it to trigger the alert.

```
this.state = {
    random: Math.floor(Math.random() * 3),
    myArray2:['one','two','three'],
    myArray: null
};


  change = () => {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    this.setState(
      {
        random: random,
        myArray: this.state.myArray2[random]
      },
      () => alert(this.state.myArray) //now refers to the new state value
    );
  };
```

See sandbox for reference: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-meadow-jumty

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is calling state inside state and trying to change value of state property without setState.
I think you should want this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    myArray2: ["one", "two", "three"],
    myArray: []
  };

  change = () => {
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    this.setState({ myArray: this.state.myArray2[random] });
    alert(this.state.myArray);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.change}>ok</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```